# formControlName value Displayed in JSON Format in Template

Tags: angular, hyperledger

```
<textarea [ngModel]="offers" formControlName="offers" 
           class="form-control" rows="3">
</textarea>
```

where **offers** is an array. It returns output **[object Object]** . How to displayed it as a **JSON** format??

Comment: What is in your `offers` array? can you provide data?

Comment: this **offers** array contains the value of a transaction name **offer**.

Comment: is it like `offers=['data 1234']` ?? if not , provide your data as example.

Comment: "offers": [
    {

      "$class": "org.bjit.tender.government.Offer",

      "bidPrice": 15,

      "listing": 

"resource:org.bjit.tender.government.TenderListing#lis17",

      "member": "resource:org.bjit.tender.government.Member#m1",

      "transactionId": "d7ea7175824f63f6a96bcaa076e29ffeee91b5fa60a04108027bf110389b85cd",

      "timestamp": "2018-04-12T02:54:32.656Z"
    }
  ]

Comment: Ok. So in your array contains lots of data. which value/Object you want to bind In your textArea?

Comment: actually I want to get output like this instead of **[object Object]**. How could I do this??  I want to convert it as a json then displayed. Is there any way to solve this??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168784/discussion-between-mehadi-hassan-and-aniket-kale).

Comment: Do you want to show all data(`offers` Array) in your textArea?

Comment: yes, I want to show all data in textarea.

Comment: Ok See my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

If offers is an array of single object than use

```
<textarea [value]="offers[0] | json" formControlName="offers" 
           class="form-control" rows="3">
</textarea>
```

if offers is an object than use

```
<textarea [value]="offers | json" formControlName="offers" 
           class="form-control" rows="3">
</textarea>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It is not working. :( Still getting **[object Object]** as output. :(

Comment: @MehadiHassan From comment, I deduced that offers is an array of single object. See if [value]="offers[0] | json"  works.

Comment: @MehadiHassan pleae use "value" instead of "ngModel". Working great on my machine.

Comment: I  have trying both "value" and "ngModel" But still it return [object Object]. :(

Comment: please disable cache or run it in private window as I think the browser is not running the updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168785/discussion-between-mehadi-hassan-and-ajay).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show data only then do simply like this.

```
 <textarea [ngModel]="offers[0] | json" formControlName="offers" class="form- 
 control" rows="3"></textarea>
```

offers is an array thats why you should have to add like this 'offers[0]'